# OpenGL Framebuffer Render to Texture not Working

Tags: java, opengl, textures, jogl, framebuffer

I'm experimenting with framebuffers to create a glow effect using Java and JOGL, but I am having problems. At the moment, my goal is to render my spaceship model, textured with an illumination texture, to a framebuffer texture and then draw the framebuffer texture to a triangle fan quad. I'm running with OpenGL 2.1 and/or 2.0 Here is my code for generating the framebuffer and its texture:

```
private int createFrameBuffer(GL2GL3 gl) {
    _frameBufferTextureId = GLHelper.makeTextureBuffer(gl, GL2GL3.GL_RGBA, _width / 2, _height / 2, 0, GL2GL3.GL_RGBA,
            GL2GL3.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2GL3.GL_REPEAT, null);
    int frameBufferId = GLHelper.makeFrameBuffer(gl, _frameBufferTextureId, _width / 2, _height / 2);
    return frameBufferId;
}

public static int makeTextureBuffer(GL2GL3 gl, int glEnumInternalFormat, int width, int height, int border,
        int glEnumPixelFormat, int glEnumPixelType, int glEnumMinFilter, int glEnumMagFilter, int glEnumWrapMode,
        File textureFile) {
    ByteBuffer textureDataBuffer = null;
    if (textureFile != null) {
        String filePath = textureFile.getPath();
        String extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, filePath.length());
        TextureData textureData = null;
        try {
            textureData = TextureIO.newTextureData(gl.getGLProfile(), textureFile, false, extension);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading texture");
        }
        textureDataBuffer = getProperlyFormattedBuffer(textureData);
    }
    IntBuffer texture = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, texture);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.get(0));
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, glEnumMinFilter);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, glEnumMagFilter);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, glEnumWrapMode);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, glEnumWrapMode);
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, glEnumInternalFormat, width, height, border, glEnumPixelFormat, glEnumPixelType,
            textureDataBuffer);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return texture.get(0);
}

public static int makeFrameBuffer(GL2GL3 gl, int textureBufferId, int width, int height) {
    IntBuffer frameBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameBuffer);
    gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer.get(0));
    gl.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL2GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBufferId, 0);
    verifyFrameBuffer(gl);
    gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL2GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    return frameBuffer.get(0);
}

private void drawTextureQuad(GL2GL3 gl) {
    _glowShader.bind(gl);
    int textureLocation = _glowShader.getUniformFields().getIlluminationTextureLocation();
    gl.glUniform1i(textureLocation, 0);
    gl.glActiveTexture(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _frameBufferTextureId);

    int vertexLocation = _glowShader.getAttributeFields().getVertexLocation();
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureQuadId);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL2GL3.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);

    int textureCoordLocation = _glowShader.getAttributeFields().getVertexTextureCoordinateLocation();
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _textureQuadCoordsId);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordLocation, 2, GL2GL3.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordLocation);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2GL3.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    _glowShader.unbind(gl);
}
```

In my render loop, I am doing the following:

```
_glowShader.bind(gl);// bind my Shader object.
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(_glowShader.getUniformFields().getProjectionMatrixLocation(), 1, true, _projectionMatrix.getBuffer());
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(_glowShader.getUniformFields().getModelViewMatrixLocation(), 1, true, _modelViewMat.getBuffer());
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebufferId);
gl.glDrawBuffers(1, _frameBufferAttachmentss); //contains GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
gl.glViewport(0, 0, _width / 2, _height / 2); // same size as texture
_spaceship.draw(gl, _glowShader);// draw method in my ModelObject class
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
_glowShader.unbind(gl);

drawTextureQuad(gl);
```

When I run this, my quad is drawn as it should, but the texture is all black. When I comment out any framebuffer bindings in my render loop, the model is rendered as it should, so I know that there is nothing wrong with my shader code. When I replace _frameBufferTextureId with another texture loaded from a file, that texture is properly drawn, so I know my texture coordinates are working and, again, my shader code is correct. Whenever I bind my frame buffer though, I don't get anything I expect. I'm also verifying my framebuffer and it is GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE.

I've read countless tutorials and posts here on stackoverflow, but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter but, in createFrameBuffer, it appears you pass the minification filter twice instead of the magnification filter.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!! Sorry if that made you uncomfortable, but that was the source of my problem! I actually should have never been passing in GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER as those are the targets in the glTexParameteri() method, not the arguments. I changed it to be GL_LINEAR for the GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_FILTER targets, and it works perfectly! :D

Comment: Ah, I don't know jogl so I couldn't figure out how the filters worked, I thought maybe they were set globally and assigned to GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER. Makes a lot more sense with your fix ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bethor pointed out, I was passing in GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER twice to my makeTextureBuffer method. This was resolving to the glTexParameteri() calls of:

```
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER);
```

which of course, makes no sense. Changing my calls to pass in GL_LINEAR fixed everything.